# Importance/Significance Of Birth Name

Tags: goddess, shakti, shaktism, kali

Wanted to ask this question : Hey guys, does it say anywhere in shastras or puran or such that the birth name of a bhakt will have influence over their chosen Isht-Dev or path of bhakti ?

So like if a woman is born with the name Lakshmi, and born with marked tendency/inclination to bhakti-marg, then does it say in scriptures anywhere that she would be expected to be a Narayan-bhakt ?

Or if she is given the birth name Sita, that she would then be expected to be Ram-bhakt ?

So, what if she is named Sita or Lakshmi and she feels strongly to do bhakti and puja of MahaDev or Shakti because she is pulled that way ?

Re Shakti/Shakta saints, RamaKrishna was given birth name Gadadhar I think (Vishnu) then given name RamaKrishna so his names were all on Narayan and avtaar of Narayan. But he venerated goddess Kali, he became Kali Maa bhakt.

What is the significance or importance of the birth name we’re given ? Is it stated somewhere in religious texts ?

Tons of Hindu people are given birth names after different gods/goddesses of Hinduism of course, but there is possibly some past life reason why someone is in particular named after Shiv or Krishn or Sarasvati or such ?

Cause they are called that name their entire life every day by people. So, something of the qualities of that deity would have an effect just from hearing that name spoken aloud over and over ? And to be given that name as a baby, some past life association or veneration was possibly there ? Or is it not like that ?

I’ve been wondering about this. Gotten into some pretty ridiculous arguments (!) in the past re given birth name versus religious inclination towards particular Isht-Dev.

Also, again, plz excuse posting so much questions, some of these things I have really been curious about for so long time with not anyone I could ask in my life as it were. Thx :)

Comment: It is customary , to consult grihya sutras , Apastamba , Aśvalāyana . ( followed in the lineage).. for any guildeline on naming (the baby on namakarana samskaara) for eg. even syllabled name for boy child, su prefix is meritorious etc . This can be combined with the Nama of one's own Ishta devata./Kula devata . But whether the child would be inclined in Bhakti marg or not could be a topic of astrology.

Comment: @Athrey Thx ! Just wondering how the name is relevant later in life to the Isht-Dev the person chooses after growing up.